# How correctly deserialize and obtain values from JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, json.net

My json:

```
[
   {
      "id": "SUPER_TOTAL",
      "title": "All",
      "ticketSales": [
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "sessions": 0,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 0,
            "ticketsPerSession": 0,
            "middlePrice": 0,
            "periodId": "SUPER_TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 15355230,
            "quantity": 88943,
            "sessions": 13171,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 1165.84,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 172.64,
            "periodId": "TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": "2020.01.22T00:00:00",
            "dateFinish": "2020.01.23T00:00:00",
            "sum": 15355230,
            "quantity": 88943,
            "sessions": 13171,
            "rupart": 65.5,
            "moneyPerSession": 1165.84,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 172.64,
            "periodId": "20200122"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": "TOTAL",
      "title": "Regions",
      "ticketSales": [
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "sessions": 0,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 0,
            "ticketsPerSession": 0,
            "middlePrice": 0,
            "periodId": "SUPER_TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 199057,
            "quantity": 1361,
            "sessions": 196,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 1015.6,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 146.26,
            "periodId": "TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": "2020.01.22T00:00:00",
            "dateFinish": "2020.01.23T00:00:00",
            "sum": 199057,
            "quantity": 1361,
            "sessions": 196,
            "rupart": 58.2,
            "moneyPerSession": 1015.6,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 146.26,
            "periodId": "20200122"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": "2400000100000",
      "title": "City",
      "ticketSales": [
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "sessions": 0,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 0,
            "ticketsPerSession": 0,
            "middlePrice": 0,
            "periodId": "SUPER_TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": null,
            "dateFinish": null,
            "sum": 199057,
            "quantity": 1361,
            "sessions": 196,
            "rupart": 0,
            "moneyPerSession": 1015.6,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 146.26,
            "periodId": "TOTAL"
         },
         {
            "dateStart": "2020.01.22T00:00:00",
            "dateFinish": "2020.01.23T00:00:00",
            "sum": 199057,
            "quantity": 1361,
            "sessions": 196,
            "rupart": 58.2,
            "moneyPerSession": 1015.6,
            "ticketsPerSession": 7,
            "middlePrice": 146.26,
            "periodId": "20200122"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Generated classes:

```
public class TicketSale
{
    public string dateStart { get; set; }
    public string dateFinish { get; set; }
    public int sum { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int sessions { get; set; }
    public double rupart { get; set; }
    public double moneyPerSession { get; set; }
    public int ticketsPerSession { get; set; }
    public double middlePrice { get; set; }
    public string periodId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<TicketSale> ticketSales { get; set; }
}
```

I need to obtain values of sum, quantity, sessions from each of ticketSales but only in the second and third objects in array, not first, because he always have zero values. So TicketSale class will be:

```
public class TicketSale
{
    public int sum { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int sessions { get; set; }
}
```

So it will be two x three = six TicketSales classes with values. Im using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried? What problem are you having in accessing the data you want? Take a look at [ask] and include a [mcve] showing your attempt at getting the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to obtain values of sum, quantity, sessions from each of ticketSales but only in the second and third objects in array, not first

If you need the TicketSales but not the first element, you can do it with a Linq query with Skip(1) statement.

**Answer you are looking for**

```
    var main = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
    var ticketSales = main.Select(x => x.ticketSales.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

main is your full json document converted and ticketSales is an array of all the ticketSales per each element of your array. If you want a collective of all of the ticketSales in one list (instead of three), you can use SelectMany

```
    var ticketSales = main.Select(x => x.ticketSales.Skip(1)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

SelectMany will put all the ticketSales in one List.

**Furthermore**

if you are interested in 1 TicketSale item with a Sum of all the TicketSales, you can create a new object based on the ticketSales variable above.

```
    TicketSale allSalesCollective = new TicketSale() 
    { 
        sum = ticketSales.Sum(x => x.sum), 
        quantity = ticketSales.Sum(x => x.quantity),
        sessions = ticketSales.Sum(x => x.sessions) 
    };
```

This will give you TicketSale with the total of sum, quantity and sessions.

Answer (score -1):

So, please use Json.Net. This is the simpiest way. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Here is example:

```
var json = "[\r\n   {\r\n      \"id\": \"SUPER_TOTAL\",\r\n      \"title\": \"All\",\r\n      \"ticketSales\": [\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 0,\r\n            \"quantity\": 0,\r\n            \"sessions\": 0,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 0,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"SUPER_TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 15355230,\r\n            \"quantity\": 88943,\r\n            \"sessions\": 13171,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1165.84,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 172.64,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": \"2020.01.22T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"dateFinish\": \"2020.01.23T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"sum\": 15355230,\r\n            \"quantity\": 88943,\r\n            \"sessions\": 13171,\r\n            \"rupart\": 65.5,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1165.84,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 172.64,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"20200122\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"id\": \"TOTAL\",\r\n      \"title\": \"Regions\",\r\n      \"ticketSales\": [\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 0,\r\n            \"quantity\": 0,\r\n            \"sessions\": 0,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 0,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"SUPER_TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 199057,\r\n            \"quantity\": 1361,\r\n            \"sessions\": 196,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1015.6,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 146.26,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": \"2020.01.22T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"dateFinish\": \"2020.01.23T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"sum\": 199057,\r\n            \"quantity\": 1361,\r\n            \"sessions\": 196,\r\n            \"rupart\": 58.2,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1015.6,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 146.26,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"20200122\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"id\": \"2400000100000\",\r\n      \"title\": \"City\",\r\n      \"ticketSales\": [\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 0,\r\n            \"quantity\": 0,\r\n            \"sessions\": 0,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 0,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 0,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"SUPER_TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": null,\r\n            \"dateFinish\": null,\r\n            \"sum\": 199057,\r\n            \"quantity\": 1361,\r\n            \"sessions\": 196,\r\n            \"rupart\": 0,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1015.6,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 146.26,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"TOTAL\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"dateStart\": \"2020.01.22T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"dateFinish\": \"2020.01.23T00:00:00\",\r\n            \"sum\": 199057,\r\n            \"quantity\": 1361,\r\n            \"sessions\": 196,\r\n            \"rupart\": 58.2,\r\n            \"moneyPerSession\": 1015.6,\r\n            \"ticketsPerSession\": 7,\r\n            \"middlePrice\": 146.26,\r\n            \"periodId\": \"20200122\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   }\r\n]";

RootObject[] root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);

foreach(var rootItem in root)
{
    rootItem.ticketSales.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

"json" is variable with json string

For remove first Items you can use RemoveAt(0)

Comment: After I Start to answer, question was changed. Firstly it was About how to deserialize it.

Comment: @TemaTre Not true. The question has not changed since it was posted; it doesn't even have a single edit.

Comment: @TemaTre Answer correct too. Thank you for the help!